# Column count not working in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

In the following bootply, why do I get two columns in chrome, but only one in firefox (v 45.0.1)? How can I get two columns in firefox?

http://www.bootply.com/j61AVJlyZc

Comment: Since you are using a `<table>` to display data, why not just alter your markup to accomplish this?

Comment: you should apply the column to tbody and reset display to tbody,tr & td http://www.bootply.com/byklmzB5FP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [w3c](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#cc)

Column Count Applies to: non-replaced block-level elements (except table elements), table cells, and inline-block elements